# Overwritten program but still in console

Tags: python, overwrite, recover

While saving my file, I accidentally overwrote it with previous project.
Now my new code is gone and I have only the old one.
In console, I have old program still running. Is there any option to recover lost code from there?
I am using Spyder anaconda

I can still see variables and can still operate on program

Comment: When you say "I can still see variables and can still operate on program" do you mean that you are in an interactive python console, with loaded modules, and you would like to write them back to some files ?

Comment: Check if your IDE can get back the previous state, or if you didn't use one, if your editor created backup files, e.g., `myfile.py~`. Try undoing in your editor.